# Scrapy Multiple loops for Multiple URLs

Tags: python, scrapy

I can get the loop to work great except I am getting 3-4 loops each time...I tried removing the start_urls reference but then the scraping stops working

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request, FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class PrinterSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'printers'
    start_urls = ['http://192.168.137.9', 'http://192.168.137.35', 'http://192.168.137.34', 'http://192.168.137.27', 'http://192.168.137.21' ]

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.xpath('//*[@name="CSRFToken"]/@value').extract_first()
        yield  FormRequest.from_response(response, formnumber=1, formdata={
            'CSRFToken' : token,
            'B55d' : 'password',
            'loginurl' : '/general/status.html'
         }, callback=self.postlogin2)


    def  postlogin2(self,response):
         for i in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(
            url = i+"/general/information.html?kind=item",
            callback=self.action)

    def action(self,response):
        drum = response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[7]/dl[1]/dd[1]/text()').extract()
        print(drum)
        for i in self.start_urls:
            yield Request(
            url = i+"/net/wired/tcpip.html",
            callback=self.action2)

    def action2(self, response):
        tcpip = response.xpath('//html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/form[1]/div[4]/dl[1]/dd[2]/input[1]/@value').extract()
        print(tcpip)
```

Comment: don't use loop but get `response.url` and use it  - `url = response.url + "/general/information.html?kind=item"` - or `url = response.urljoin("/general/information.html?kind=item"` [response.urljoin](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin)

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy uses elements from `start_urls` to run `parse()` - later you should get url from `response` without loop.

```
def postlogin2(self, response):
    yield Request(
        response.url + "/general/information.html?kind=item",
        callback=self.action)
```

or rather

```
def postlogin2(self, response):
    yield Request(
        response.urljoin("/general/information.html?kind=item"),
        callback=self.action)
```

or

```
def postlogin2(self, response):
    yield response.follow("/general/information.html?kind=item", callback=self.action)
```

Do the same with other loops.

Doc: [Response.urljoin()](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin), [Response.follow()](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.follow)